# How to find nearest points in vectors?

Tags: matlab

I have a 71x4 table which represents: name of some climate station and corresponding latitude, longitude, and elevation.

In this list, I want to find the nearest point together. I mean in the output I want to have one nearest station for every 71 stations that I have. I want to use the Euclidean distance.
I was share `coordinates.mat` here in the [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LrnFNDdXMbXuSj6WcGLSZ3jWtYB7zJ3W)

**UPDATE**
Here is my code. I think It would be awesome if I can run my code for one station then using for loop to generalized it. I have some station names and corresponding latitude, longitude and elevation. I want to find the nearest stations. In fact for each row, I need to compute the distance to all other rows and pick the one with the smallest distance.

```
Ahvaz = coordinates{5,{'lat','lon','station_elevation'}};
coordinates(5,:)=[]
All = coordinates{:,{'lat','lon','station_elevation'}};
distances = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, All, Ahvaz).^2,2));
closest = All(distances==min(distances),:);
```

I don't know how to optimize it. every time I want to go to next station I should change this code by hand and look at list of coordinates to find the name of nearest station.
As you can see I'm not a professional one. I want to do this for my field of study which is water resources management, and I'm not specialized in Matlab code.

Comment: For each point, you need to compute the distance to all other points, and pick the one with the smallest distance. You can save some computation by realizing that the distances are symmetric, and so you need to compute only n*(n-1)/2 distances.

Comment: The way S.O works is that you show what you've tried and and say what didn't work. Show us your code.

Comment: Dear @Justin I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The must easiest way is to use [`knnsearch(...,'k',1)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) with `'K',1` since you want so see just the nearest point. However, the function requires the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox. Otherwise, you will need to code it yourself, looping through all points and calculating the distance to all other points as was said before.

Comment: Dear max, Thank you, Do you think the below code can be used too? I get right answer using this code without KNN. 
`dist = sqrt((coordinates.lon - coordinates.lon').^2 + (coordinates.lat - coordinates.lat').^2);
dist(dist == 0) = Inf;
[~,closest_id] = min(dist);
coordinates.closest_station = coordinates.station_name(closest_id);`
I simply ignore elevation and that is okey for me. Can I know your opinion? Thanks

Comment: @Bozemaje yes, that should work as well. (Note that `'` is the complex transpose. It's better style if you use `.'` but your code should work anyway)